# Cut smaller threads on stud?

Tags: stripped-thread, thread, tap

The on floor panel of my car, I have studs that stick up and are M8x1.25.  On one of these studs the threads are mangled enough where my M8x1.25 die is essentially cutting the remaining threads.

Is it possible to take a M7x1.0 die and cut new threads on the stud?  Would I need to do any sort of preparation before doing so?  Perhaps step down to M6?

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to get an M7 (or M6) die to cut an M8 down to that size.  Instead of an M8 die how about an M8 thread chaser?

Answer (score 1):

You can possibly do what you're suggesting, however, by the time you get through cutting on it, there isn't going to be much left (if there's anything left at all).

A better option might be to cut what's left of the stud off flush, then drill a hole where the stud was at. You could then use an M8x1.25 bolt to replace the stud. You could then weld the head of the bolt to the floor panel, or if a welder is not available, superglue would most likely keep it in place long enough while you tighten down the nut.

Comment: I think replacing the stud with a nut might be difficult as the drive shaft is right below the stud, so accessing underneath there would be quite difficult.

Comment: Drive shafts are usually pretty easy to remove to give you access to the underside of the floor pan.